# Getting Started: FB C# on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

Sorry if this is somewhere in the Discussion history, but I didn't see a "hello world wp7" type sample here or in the Doc section.  Is there a sample kicking around that I can use?

Here's what I'd like to do:

Use FB C# to integrate facebook like and facebook wall posts into my games (XNA based... not sure it matters thou).

1 I'd like to allow players to sign in using their facebook account and "like" a game

2 I'd like to save their sign-in state between game play sessions

3 When a player completes an objective e.g. kills a boss, I'd like to post a message along with picture to so their friends can see their accomplishment

... is this doable?  Is there a sample for it?

Comment: Lots of samples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx you may also want to read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

It is most certainly possible to do this. There are probably not many (if any) samples floating around that would do exactly what you mentioned. I would recommend to go through the [API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) first. Also, remember that with the Mango SDK update, you now have access to `ShareStatusTask` and `ShareLinkTask`, that allow Facebook integration to be present in your application as long as an active Facebook account is registered with the device.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I'll troll through the API and let you know when I have any questions.  Cheers!

Comment: Actually is there a general HelloWorld started sample for WP7... that would be great :).